# Other options under "Cut, copy, and paste" not found - Microsoft Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

Just wanted to ask why there are so many missing options for "Cut, copy, and paste" in my current version of Excel (Office 365,  (Version 2306 Build 16.0.16529.20164) 64-bit). I'm trying to set the default paste behaviour for Excel - many websites suggest to edit options under the "Cut, copy, and paste" section, but it just simply doesn't exist for my installation of Excel.

Suppposed "Cut, copy, and paste" options

[image: Suppposed "Cut, copy, and paste" options]

Current "Cut, copy, and paste" options under Excel Advanced options

[image: Current "Cut, copy, and paste" options under Excel Advanced options]

Comment: Are you sure those websites you were looking at were specifically applicable to Excel?  For example - this page, from Microsoft (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/control-the-formatting-when-you-paste-text-20156a41-520e-48a6-8680-fb9ce15bf3d6) which seems to have a similar screenshot to the one you've noted, is applicable to Word only, not Excel.   I don't believe Excel has the same level of configurable options

Comment: This feature is in Word.